# Волшебница-зима или волшебница зима?

Tags: орфография, приложение, раздельно-дефис

Александр Пушкин

**Волшебница-зима**

*Вот север, тучи нагоняя,*

*Дохнул, завыл — и вот сама*

*Идет **волшебница-зима**.*

https://www.culture.ru/poems/5091/volshebnica-zima

1. Здесь мы видим дефисное написание: ***волшебница-зима***.  А как правильно?  Правила ПАС под ред. Лопатина предлагают дефисное написание приложений **в любой позиции,** но по Розенталю приложение **в препозиции** может писаться раздельно, если имеет **качественное** значение (волшебная зима).  Для сравнения: зима-волшебница, единственная форма.
2. **Так почему же дефис?** В первых изданиях "Евгения Онегина"  раздельное письмо: ***волшебница зима***.  А как  его выбрал А.С. Пушкин, по какому орфографическому учебнику? Увы, их тогда не было, первый свод **правил Грота** (предшественник наших Правил 1956 года) появился только в 1885 году.

Ну что-нибудь у него было, грамматика  какая?  С другой стороны, дефис совсем недавно закрепился в качестве письменного знака, так что, наверное, он ничего не выбирал.
Но в последующих изданиях дефис встречается, хотя и не везде. Да и в Интернете сейчас можно найти разные варианты.

3. **А как правильно?**  И не только по учебникам, **а по существу**? Меня интересует ваше мнение, даже, может быть, **ваша интуиция**. То есть не формальный подход, а **чувство языка**.  Ведь дефисное написание можно определить даже на слух.  Царевич Иван и Иван-царевич, река Москва и Москва-река – такие сочетания читаются по-разному.

**Вопросы такие:**

1. В каких изданиях А.С. Пушкина (в том числе академических) стали использовать дефис?
2. Какая форма вам кажется более корректной и почему?

Вопрос зимний, предновогодний и, возможно, конкурсный, если будут ответы.

Comment: Выбрал бы вариант без дефиса и без Розенталя, потому что похоже на следующее: *волшебница Зима* (имя). За счёт такого художественного приёма зиме как бы придаётся одушевлённость. А при обратном порядке слов написал бы с дефисом.

Comment: Вот когда будете писать свой роман в стихах, тогда и напишете: волшебница Зима. А в настоящий момент такие сочетания я "рекомендую" вам писать по слуху.  Раздельное и дефисное написания легко различаются по наличию паузы. Волшебница-зима – слитное произношение, это единый образ. Неплохой выбор. Волшебница зима – раздельное произношение обычного словосочетания. Это тоже вариант. Один вариант соответствует ПАС, а другой – Розенталю, так что вы всегда будете в правовом поле.  Так что выбираете? (По слуху и по художественному пониманию образа.)

Comment: В целом согласен. Уже ж сделал выбор. Раздельное написание более художественное.

Comment: Неужели согласны? Со мной, хотя бы целом!  Ах, oleedd, 
этот день я  для себя отмечу  белым камешком! А мне теперь больше нравится волшебница-зима как единый образ.

Comment: Что за белый камушек? Выражение какое-то? А мне не нравится произносить слитно. Как же у вас взгляды меняются. К примеру, для учёных это плохо. В науке нужны твёрдые позиции.

Comment: Ну что тут поделаешь!  Я и сама себя не узнаю.  Мне кажется, что мой прежний ответ написан лет пять назад,  и стиль речи какой-то странный...  А про белый камешек можно прочитать здесь  https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/latin_proverbs/3370/День  Красиво римляне говорили...

Answer (score 2):

Ответ.

Скажу сразу, что лично я сторонник, в случае разногласия с розенталевским, именно лопатинского справочника. Просто потому, что он новее и учитывает тенденции последних десятилетий.

Разные редакции классиков -- вопрос непростой для меня. Понимаю, что мы сейчас читаем не оригинальные произведения классиков, а очень даже переводы, вернее переложения, с дореформенного на современный русский. Вероятно, для каждого конкретного академического издания конкретного автора составлялся некий свод правил, чтобы все тексты привести к единообразию. Чем руководствовались редакторы/корректоры в каждом случае -- можно, мне кажется, только гадать (если методология не раскрывается в предисловии, как это бывает).

Конечно, всегда можно списать на авторский стиль или банальную ошибку. У Л. Толстого, к примеру, встречаются совершенно невозможные в литературном языке конструкции наподобие "убедившись, что понять этого он не может, ему стало скучно. Потом, вспомнив всё то волнение и озлобление, которые он видел на всех лицах, ему стало грустно" (Анна Каренина).

Что касается изданий Пушкина, в издании Academia (1936—1938) и в парижском издании 1937 года "Зима" написана с прописной буквы (в предыдущих и последующих изданиях -- нет). А вот дефиса нет нигде! Я просмотрел все издания Е.О., что выложены [здесь](http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=10326), и не нашёл ни в одном.

Comment: Зима с прописной была ещё в издании 1837-го года. [Здесь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xmUNAQAAIAAJ&pg=PT18&dq=%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB4svW1Pz0AhWciv0HHVWTBbsQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD&f=false) факсимильная копия того издания. Зима с прописной была также в "Пире во время чумы" (там "проказница Зима"). Потом во многих изданиях писали со строчной, а Томашевский оставлял прописную — но только в "Пире...".

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Интересно, почему в 1837 напечатали "Зима", а в 1838 -- "зима".

Comment: @Nektoid  Ну что тут скажешь... Когда я подбирала текст для вопроса, то  прочитала интересную информацию об истории орфографии вообще. И общая картина стала яснее. Не было у нас раньше никаких правил вообще, а первый работа Грота по орфографии называлась "Спорные вопросы русского правописания от Петра Великого доныне» (1873). Понимаете, спорные вопросы были, а само понятие правил это уже в его следующей книге. «Русское правописание: Руководство, составленное по поручению Императорской Академии наук» (1885) стало первым в истории обучения языку орфографическим руководством.

Comment: Вот такие дела. Учились по Гроту и до революции и после. А да него современники оценивали орфографию как «область, в которой процветает... полнейшая неразбериха... в ней господствует, за весьма ничтожным исключением, самый дикий, невежественный, бесшабашный произвол. Все это надо учитывать, когда мы с вами говорим об изданиях Пушкина.

Comment: @sharon а я всегда говорил, кстати, что ссылаться на творения догротовских писателей/поэтов (в аутентичном виде) как на аргументы в пунктуационных спорах -- затея глупая)) Там чего только не встретишь.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, через дефис иногда пишут прозвища, которые должны восприниматься как единое целое. Вспомнить Сами-Знаете-Кого. Можно же, к примеру, написать: "Вон, смотри, по улице идёт не-твой-парень!"? Сразу многое читается в таком наименовании: и ехидство той, что восклицает, и история той, к которой это восклицание обращено -- она влюблена, а он френдзонит...

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Комментарий я дам в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий к ответу

**Ваша идея заслуживает внимания**, но в этой теме существует правило Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111  Пункт 4. Дефис не пишется:

1. если предшествующее однословное приложение может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному: красавец мужчина (ср.: красивый мужчина), старик отец, гигант завод (но: завод-гигант), бедняк сапожник, богатырь всадник, крошка сиротка, хищник волк, искусник повар.

Написание «***волшебница зима***» соответствует правилу Розенталя, а при дефисном написании мы не соблюдаем это правило. Впрочем, оно применяется не вполне последовательно. Например,  у Тютчева: «***чародейкою зимою*** околдован лес стоит», а у Крылова «***проказница-мартышка***».

И мне интересно, как менялось написание в романе  у Пушкина.  Ведь было несколько академических изданий его произведений. **Когда там появился дефис**, как это объяснялось  и что сейчас считается нормой?

Идея единства хороша, но она непопулярна среди наших пользователей. Они понимают два объяснения: или там приложение с качественным значением прилагательного, или это просто два самостоятельных нарицательных существительных.

Или вот такой вопрос: Как правильно пишется "волшебница зима" и "зима волшебница"? http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3925604-kak-pravilno-pishetsja-volshebnica-zima-i-zima-volshebnica.html

Как на него отвечать? И как относиться к разным редакциям романа Пушкина?

Comment: Отвечу тоже  в виде ответа.